# Where should we download tinymce popup file with full implementation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce-4

I am using tiny mce text editor in asp.net application from this plugin  http://www.tinymce.com. 
I am using http://www.roxyfileman.com/TinyMCE-file-browser for adding file browser 
feature in mce text editor. Now I am trying to call

```
 var win = tinyMCE.getWindowArg("window");
```

from this tutorial http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser as shown in

```
function mySubmit() {
//call this function only after page has loaded
//otherwise tinyMCEPopup.close will close the
//"Insert/Edit Image" or "Insert/Edit Link" window instead

var URL = document.my_form.my_field.value;
var win = tinyMCE.getWindowArg("window");

 // insert information now
  win.document.getElementById(tinyMCE.getWindowArg("input")).value = URL;

  // for image browsers: update image dimensions
  if (win.getImageData) win.getImageData();

  // close popup window
  tinyMCEPopup.close();
}
```

on submit button click, it throws two errors

> - Uncaught TypeError: `t.editor.windowManager.createInstance` is not a function `tinyMCEPopup.init @ tinymcepopup.js:26(anonymous function) @ tinymcepopup.js:274 2ImageUpload.html?type=image&input=mceu_96-inp&value=:16`
> - Uncaught TypeError: `tinyMCE.getWindowArg` is not a function

Please help me !!!

Answer (score 4):

I just spent ALL DAY trying to figure this out. Turns out you don't need tiny_mce_popup.js at all!

I Finally came up with this solution based on this tutorial:
https://pixabay.com/en/blog/posts/direct-image-uploads-in-tinymce-4-42/.

I hope it helps.

I'm using TinyMCE 4, btw.

There are are two files:

**1. File With TinyMCE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function RoxyFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
          // alert("Field_Name: " + field_name + "nURL: " + url + "nType: " + type + "nWin: " + win); // debug/testing

  var roxyFileman = 'browse_files.php';
  if (roxyFileman.indexOf("?") < 0) {     
    roxyFileman += "?type=" + type;   
  }
  else {
    roxyFileman += "&type=" + type;
  }
  roxyFileman += '&input=' + field_name + '&value=' + win.document.getElementById(field_name).value;
  if(tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language){
    roxyFileman += '&langCode=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language;
  }
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
     file: roxyFileman,
     title: 'Roxy Fileman',
     width: 850, 
     height: 650,
     resizable: "yes",
     plugins: "media",
     inline: "yes",
     close_previous: "no"  
  }, {     window: win,     input: field_name    });
  return false; 
    }
    tinymce.init({
        selector: "textarea",
        theme: "modern",
        force_br_newlines : false,
        force_p_newlines : false,
        forced_root_block : '',
        plugins: [
            "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak",
            "searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
            "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality",
            "emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools"
        ],
        toolbar1: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image", 
        file_browser_callback: RoxyFileBrowser,
        toolbar2: "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
        image_advtab: true,
        templates: [
            {title: 'Test template 1', content: 'Test 1'},
            {title: 'Test template 2', content: 'Test 2'}
        ]
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="my_editor"></textarea>
    <input name="image" type="text" style="display:none;"  onchange="$('#my_form').submit();this.value='';">
</body>
</html>
```

**2. File With The Image Browser Content/browse_files.php**
(This can be any format. php, html, asp...etc.)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.image_choice').bind('click', function(){

    var image_url = $(this).attr("src");

    //ADDS THE URL TO THE IMAGE FIELD THIS IS WHERE I GOT HUNG UP!
    parent.$('.mce-btn.mce-open').parent().find('.mce-textbox').val(image_url);

    var ed = parent.tinymce.editors[0];
    ed.windowManager.windows[1].close();// CLOSES THE BROWSER WINDOW
});
});
</script>
<style>
.image_choice {
width:150px;    
}
</style>
<!-- DISPLAY YOUR IMAGES AS THUMBNAILS MUCH NICER THAN I HAVE ;-)  -->
<img src="../images/image1.gif" class="image_choice"  />
<img src="../images/image1.gif" class="image_choice"  />
<img src="../images/image1.gif" class="image_choice"  />
<img src="../images/image1.gif" class="image_choice"  />
<!-- ETC...-->
```

If you absolutely need tiny_mce_popup.js, you can find it here:
http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/js/tinymce/tiny_mce_popup.js.source.txt

Comment: Thank You! I added: `var editor = parent.tinymce.editors[0];` and then `editor.insertContent("<p>Content</p>")` works a treat! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i make a simple jquery code put it in ur link.php or image.php and it wil work

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   var parentWin = (!window.frameElement && window.dialogArguments) ||        opener || parent || top;
   $(   function() {
     $('img').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    imgAlt = $(this).attr('alt');
    divInput =                         $("input#"+parentWin.inputSrc,parent.document).parent().attr('id');
    divInputSplit = divInput.split("_");
    divTitle = "mce_"+(parseInt(divInputSplit[1],10) +1);
    $("input#"+parentWin.inputSrc,parent.document).val(imgSrc);
    $("input#"+divTitle,parent.document).val(imgAlt);
    $(".mce-close",parent.document).last().trigger("click");
     });
    });
    </script>
```

fore more detail visit [zrclassroom.com](http://zrclassroom.com/toturials/tinymce4-instalation-et-configuration-du-tinymce-file-browser-ajout-des-lien-et-des-image-184)